# Find all subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}/ 5 \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/125 \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory

The question is as follow:

> Find all subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}/ 5 \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/125 \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ and prove there is no abelian group of order 21.

I'm quite buffled by how to approach this but I know that *maybe* this is equivalent to:

> $\mathbb{Z}/ 5 \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/ 5 \mathbb{Z} \times\mathbb{Z}/ 5 \mathbb{Z} \times\mathbb{Z}/ 5 \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$

and also 21 is not a divide of 125 or 5 so it seems just odd.

so any help is appreciated.

Comment: $\Bbb{Z}_{21}$ is an abelian group of order 21.

Comment: The two groups are not isomorphic. The first one has an element of order $125$, and the second one has only elements of order $1$, $5$ or $\infty$.